# How to cast to a type that is only known at runtime

Tags: generics, kotlin, typing

Is there a (elegant) way to cast to a type that is only available at runtime? Pls check this out:

```
data class Foo<T> (
    var value: T
)

val foos = listOf<Foo<*>>(
    Foo(value = "I a a String"),
    Foo(value = 1),
    Foo(value = true)
)

val anyTypes = listOf<Any>("String", 1, false)

fun main() {

    foos.forEachIndexed() { idx, foo ->
       foo.value = anyTypes[idx]
    }

    foos.forEach(::println)
}
```

Oh and it is not possible to create a list for each type separately! ;-)

Comment: why not `val foos = listOf<Foo<Any>>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the type argument of each `Foo` isn't known at runtime at all.

There is no perfect way to solve this problem, because using generics like this is inherently unsafe. There may be a way to rethink your solution to avoid this altogether (mutating values of star-projected types is generally a bad idea, **which is why the type system prevents you from assigning anything but `null` to values of upper-bounded invariant types**.)

You'll have to provide the type itself as an argument to each `Foo`:

```
data class Foo<T : Any> (
    val type: KClass<T>,
    var value: T
)

val foos = listOf<Foo<*>>(
    Foo(String::class, value = "I a a String"),
    Foo(Int::class, value = 1),
    Foo(Boolean::class, value = true)
)

val anyTypes = listOf<Any>("String", 1, false)

...
foos.forEachIndexed { idx, foo ->
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    (foo as Foo<Any>).value = foo.type.cast(anyTypes[idx])
}

foos.forEach(::println)
```

You could also omit the `KClass` argument and go without the cast, but then you risk silently accepting values of the wrong type, which will only fail when the value is accessed and used.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to manage the value type in Foo as additional parameter, I solved this by letting foo itself handle the casting and setting of Foo.value. Like this:

```kotlin
data class Foo<T> (
    var value: T
) {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun tryCastAndSet(anything: Any) {
        value = anything as T
    }
}

val foos = listOf<Foo<*>>(
    Foo(value = "I a a String"),
    Foo(value = 1),
    Foo(value = true)
)

val anys = listOf<Any>("String", 1, false)

fun main() {

    foos.forEachIndexed { idx, foo ->
       foo.tryCastAndSet(anys[idx])
    }

    foos.forEach(::println)
}
```

I think this probably the most elegant way there is for this problem.

Comment: This _compiles_, but the cast won't actually do anything, so you won't encounter any errors when inserting values of the wrong type. Replace any of the values in `anys` with values of a different type and you'll notice nothing will change; the program will [break](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-class-cast-exception/) as soon as the value is accessed and used as if it were a `T`.